# Osculating circle with level curve of function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, osculating-circle

Find the osculating circle $C$ of the parabola $x^2+y=0$ at the origin $(0,0)$. Find a function $f(x,y)$ such that $C$ is a level curve of $f$.

Please, solve the problem completely with precise function $f$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any help, please?!

Comment: I’m surprised that this question hasn’t already been downvoted and on its way to being closed. This isn’t a “do my homework for me site.” You’re expected to provide some context for the problem and show some effort of your own to solve it. If you’d like to have a better chance of attracting an answer instead of being closed as at least two of your other questions have been, read through [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and edit your question to include the information described there.

Comment: @amd What I do not like in this forum is the users being very rude to newcomers and sometimes insulting them as if we have done very wrong thing in this website! Hope this situation will change eventually, esp. in math stack exchange!